# Detect when flexslider has loaded first slide

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am using [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) and I am making a calculataion of the height/posn of another element via jquery something like below. The `.flexslider ul li img` doesnt work though. I need to make sure that the flexslider slide is fully loaded so that I can measure it's height, but I can't target it. I have proved the concept using `setTimeout()` but I cant know how long the image will take to load on any given server so I want to have it depend on whether or not the flexslider is at it's final dimensions. How can I make this work.

**Callback** (from documentation): I see from the documentation page that `start: function(){}` is a property which "*Fires when the slider loads the first slide*" but I dont now how to use it. I guess that might be a better way around it.

```
var resizeBackground = $('.flexslider ul li img').load(function(){

 $('.home .skin-background').css({
     'display': 'block',
     'height': $fpTop.outerHeight(true) + $quickBar.height() - 1 + 'px',
 });

});

$(window).load(resizeBackground).resize(resizeBackground);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was a bit complicated because of the resize code that I also wanted but basically I ended up putting the above code into a function and instead of calling on the load I called it from where I instantiated flexslider like this

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({

    ... etc ...

    start: function(slider){

    ... etc ...

        sizeSkin(); // This is the function that I put the code in

    }
});
```